# crash when trying to give a space in cstring

Tags: c++

I wrote a console program and if i give a space in     fp->kind then it crashes. Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>

struct fish
{
char kind[40];
float lenght;
float weight;
};

int main()
{
using std::cout;
using std::cin;

fish* fp = new fish();

cout<<"enter the kind of fish: ";
cin>>fp->kind;
cout<<"\nenter the weight of the fish: ";
cin>>fp->weight;
cout<<"\nenter the lenght of the fish: ";
cin>>fp->lenght;
cout<<"\nKind: "<<fp->kind
    <<"\nlenght: "<<fp->lenght
<<"\nweight: "<<(*fp).weight;
cin.get();
cin.get();
delete fp;
return 0;
}
```

and it doesn't crash if i don't give a space.

PS im using Visual Studio 2012.
and here is the debug output.

```
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Dark Vadar\Documents\Visual Studio      2012\Projects\Project1\Debug\Project1.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the   PDB file.
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open  the PDB file.
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp110d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcr110d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
 The program '[1848] Project1.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: cin.getline(fp->kind, 39);

Comment: im trying to set fp->kind to "gold fish"

Comment: There's no reason to allocate `fp` on the heap. This looks like a bad Java habit that you need to get out of if you're going to be using C++.

Comment: I was trying solving a Question on c++ primer that says allocate fp on the heap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cin` uses white space to separate input tokens.
Example:

```
//Input: apples oranges
cin >> str1;
cin >> str2;
//You get str1 = "apples", str2 = "oranges"
```

In your code, if you enter space for the first `cin>>` prompt like "A B".

fp->kind is set to "A"
fp->weight is set to "B" which cin reads in next and tries to convert to float but fails.

You need use [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/) to read entire line instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <string>

//...

struct fish
{
    std::string kind;
    float lenght;
    float weight;
};
```

is the correct implementation without raw-array-induced vulnerabilities.

By the way, your crash isn't caused by entering a whitespace but rather by buffer overflow.

Comment: I'm trying to do it with cstrings

Comment: The code above does not prevent the bug with the ' ' character. It is probably because the standard c++ streams delimit the items by spaces. There should be some methods for the standard C streams that allow you to take spaces in user input. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. It doesn't cause any vulnerabilities, like those Jule mentioned above, and will take any number of spaces or super-special characters in the "kind" field. Note that this uses the default c streams. I use these because they can be tightly controlled. Note the "39" after the '%' in scanf. That prevents it from reading any more than 39 characters, leaving one more spot for the null-terminator.

```
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

struct fish
{
    char kind[40];
    float length;
    float weight;
};

int main()
{
    fish* fp = new fish();

    printf("enter the kind of fish: ");
    scanf("%39[^\n]", fp->kind);
    printf("enter the weight of the fish: ");
    scanf("%f", &(fp->weight));
    printf("enter the length of the fish: ");
    scanf("%f", &(fp->length));
    printf("\nKind: %s\nlength: %f\nweight: %f\n", fp->kind, fp->length, fp->weight);
    delete fp;
    return 0;
}
```